# How to include select2 using angular or Zepto JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, zepto, angularjs-select2

I have developed one mobile application using Ionic framework with angular JS.

Now I have worked on select box but user wants search type of(Select2) select box but I won't use jQuery and select2 plugins in my application but I can use `Zepto.js` and angular JS.

So, Guys if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 is available for angularjs. Please check the following github page for the same.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Let me know if you need some more input here.